# Markdown table without bold heading

Tags: markdown

How can I make a markdown table where the heading isn't bold?

```
| content 1  | babbad |
|content2 | dsfa |
| content 3  | safds  |
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try using CSS hack:

```
|<span style="font-weight:normal">heading</span>|
|:---------------------------------------------:|
|              content is king                  |
```

This is in fact not an extended Markdown or Github Flavored Markdown.